# Entity Framework with SQLite

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sqlite, ado.net

I am trying to create entities out of a SQLite database. SQLite doesnt have foreign keys, therefore I cannot map associations between entities. Is there a way to map them somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite 3.6.19 supports foreign keys.

http://www.sqlite.org/draft/foreignkeys.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually previous versions do "support" foreign keys, but it doesn't enforce them. This means that you can declare the foreign keys and the EF designer will pick up the entity relationships.